# Flutter convert font points to logical pizels

Tags: flutter

I love using logical pixels in flutter for cross-platform graphics layout.  Right now, I'm trying to write a Stack that mixes Text objects with CustomPaint objects.  It would be nice to convert between logical pixels and typographical points to work out where to place the objects.

I'm guessing there must be a fixed ratio between logical pixels and points, so that fonts scale with everything else on the screen.  But, I can't find what that ratio is.

Is there an fixed ratio for pixels:points, or some other way to convert between the two units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RenderParagraph](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderParagraph-class.html) to paint any text in any font, and get the size information for it.  You can call `getDryLayout` to get a lot of the information, and there are other getters as well for things like baseline.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  What about going the other way?  What if I have a speech bubble with a height in pixels, and I want to figure out what size text will fill it?

Comment: The auto_size_text package can do that.

Comment: That looks great!  I didn't find that package before.  Thanks!